# How can I play audio through non-apple bluetooth earphones without distortion

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avaudiosession

I have an iPhone app that plays back **prerecorded video clips**. The audio sounds fine from the phone speaker or applepods, but when I listen through bluetooth connected headphones/speakers that are not apple it sounds terribly distorted. I have tried to use AVAUDIOSESESSION to fix the problem, but no luck. This is the code I tried (from another similar stack overflow answer):

```
         var error: NSError?
         var success: Bool?

         override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

       // so we can play the audio undistorted through bluetooth headphones:

       do {
           try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord,
           mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay,
           .allowBluetoothA2DP,.defaultToSpeaker])

       try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    
       } catch let error1 as NSError {
           error = error1
           success = false
       }
          if !success! { 
          print("Failed to set audio session category.  Error: \(error!)")
       }
```

I am a first time developer so I need things explained very simply and from the basics up. Thank  you so much.

Comment: You also should call this method to activate/deactivate current session https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616597-setactive

Comment: Thanks vpoltave. Added this line : try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true), but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

It was an embarrassing error. I hope no one else makes it.

The range of AVPlayer's volume must be between 0.0 and 1.0. If you set the volume louder than this (I had player.volume = 7, instead of player.volume = 0.7) you will get distortion on non-apple bluetooth headphones for some reason (apple earphones and the internal speaker accommodates for this error).